# Stuck On Adding Ability to Switch Player Turns in Tic-Tac-Toe Game

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements

Trying to build the tic-tac-toe game and stuck on the part with the alternation of players. The player marks ('X' or 'O') are defined in the factory function that creates the players. I am able to get it to where the squares on the gameBoard can populate the appropriate mark, but I can't seem to figure out why it will not alternate between player 1 and player 2.

```
//Tic-Tac-Toe board pieces and DOM elements
let ticTacToeBoard = (function() {
  let topLeft = document.querySelector('#top-left')
  let topMid = document.querySelector('#top-mid')
  let topRight = document.querySelector('#top-right')
  let midLeft = document.querySelector('#mid-left')
  let midMid = document.querySelector('#mid-mid')
  let midRight = document.querySelector('#mid-right')
  let botLeft = document.querySelector('#bot-left')
  let botMid = document.querySelector('#bot-mid')
  let botRight = document.querySelector('#bot-right')
  let gameBoard = []


  let gridSquares = () => {
    gameBoard = [topLeft, topMid, topRight,
      midLeft, midMid, midRight,
      botLeft, botMid, botRight
    ]
    // let gridSquares = cacheDom
    // // let gridSquares = document.querySelectorAll('.game-square')
    // let squares = [...gridSquares]
    for (let square of gameBoard) {
      square.textContent = ''
    }
  }

  gridSquares()

  return {
    gridSquares,
    gameBoard
  }
})()
//Player factory function
const Player = function(name, move, marker) {

  const boardMove = () => {
    for (let place of ticTacToeBoard.gameBoard) {
      place.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        e.target.textContent = marker
      })
    }
  }
  return {
    name,
    move,
    boardMove,
    marker
  }
}
//Logic that creates player moves for both players
let playerMoves = (function() {
  // let turn = true;
  const playerOne = Player('player-one', 1, 'X')
  const playerTwo = Player('player-two', 2, 'O')

  //Function that alternates players turns
  function markBoard() {
    let turn = true;
    if (turn === true) {
      return playerOne.boardMove()
      turn = false;
    } else if (turn === false) {
      return playerTwo.boardMove()
      turn = true;
    }
  }

  markBoard()


  return {
    playerOne,
    playerTwo,
    markBoard
  }

})()


let game = (function() {})()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things wrong with your `markBoard` method, first every time you call the function you set `turn` to `true` which means player 2 will never get the turn, so you will need to initiate the variable only once outside the function, second you return out of the function before setting the variable to its opposite. So if you change it to something along the likes of this it should work:

```js
let turn = true;

function markBoard() {
  if (turn) {
    turn = false;
    return playerOne.boardMove()
  } else {
    turn = true;
    return playerTwo.boardMove()
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey @LeeLenaLee - I tried that but it did not work unfortunately. Is there something wrong with my factory function possibly? Specifically the method inside.